# Prism DI container from Android background service

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

My app has a background service that may be run independently of the main app (HostApduService).

How can I access/use Prism's IContainer from this background service?

I am aware that IContainer is available from Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, see:

https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/45097342/implement+dependency+injection+in+background+services+in+xamarin+forms+using+prism

However it is possible in my case that the App doesn't exist, if the service is run without bringing up the app itself.

Comment: Is you service a separate process? Then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple options for you if `App.Current` is null.

1) in your background service initialize a new instance of the App:

```
var app = new App();
app.Container.Resolve<IMyService>();
```

2) use a helper method that only registers what you want and create the container you need for your background service:

```
public class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        RegisterBackgroundServices(containerRegistry);
    }

    public static void RegisterBackgroundServices(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        // Register services you need in the Background Service
    }
}

public class MyBackgroundService
{
    IContainerExtension Container { get; }
    public MyBackgroundService()
    {
        // Note: Prism has some non-default Rules in place
        Container = new DryIocContainerExtension(new Container());
        App.RegisterBackgroundServices(Container);
    }
}
```

Comment: One should note, though, that it is not _the app's container_, but a distinct one, so for each singleton the app has one and the service has a different one. I suppose, the OP is looking for a way to share a container between the service and the app.

Comment: @Haukinger, if you're truly backgrounded in the event that the app itself is not running then it shouldn't matter that you are using your own container as long as you have the correct registrations with that container. As I recall when there is an active app from Android you should be able to access the static reference to `App.Current`.

Comment: Tthat would be really cool. I'll have a look into that when I find time.

Comment: I can confirm that when app is active the background service shares the Container